# How to create notification channel to android less than O

Tags: android, push-notification

when I am trying to make my project target Android less than 8.0 and make Build Version code kitkat it keeps saying call require 26 need some help plz

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

Answer (score 1):

It means this will only work for Android Oreo and up.

You dont need to create a notification channel for version codes under Oreo. I mean you can skip this step.

Comment: so how can I create class MyFirebaseMessagingService do you know a github project that have the class and target android below 8.0 thanks